# SQLite cursor error: Out of memory

Tags: android

I have a memory problem that I can't figure out.

```
12-17 00:03:10.603: E/AndroidRuntime(19910): android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=723 (# cursors opened by this proc=723)
```

This happens only when I refresh the page 15-20 times(each time make something like 30 query).

```
        Cursor c;

        for(w = 0; w < 30; w++)
        {   
            ...
            c = dataBase.fetchA();  

            int valueColIncome = c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.IEMetaData.IE_VALUE); 

            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {  
                do              
                {   
                    ...
                }while(c.moveToNext()); 
            }

            c = dataBase.fetchB();

            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {  
                do              
                {                   
                    ...
                }while(c.moveToNext()); 
            }
            ...                
        }
        c.close();
```

I also try to create a cursor every loop in the for and then close it, but nothing has changed.
When I refresh this activity more than 15 times the exception is throw.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340257/sqlite-android-database-cursor-window-allocation-of-2048-kb-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your cursors!:

```
    for(w = 0; w < 30; w++)
    {   
        ...
        c = dataBase.fetchA();  

        int valueColIncome = c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.IEMetaData.IE_VALUE); 

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {  
            do              
            {   
                ...
            }while(c.moveToNext()); 
        }
        c.close();

        c = dataBase.fetchB();

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {  
            do              
            {                   
                ...
            }while(c.moveToNext()); 
        }
        c.close();
        ...                
    }
```

> **Most often the cause for this error are non closed cursors.**

Answer (score 0):

@Jorgesys answer is mostly done.
I think it should solve the problem.
The reason is Cursor is not close for every time, but it is better to have

```
for() {
Cursor c;
.....
c.close();
}
```

One thing to remember is that, the android Cursor windows **is limited to 2Mb.**
So when you query the data (especially the BLOB), **the size should not be bigger the limitation**.
To solve that problem, **divide you query into smaller part** or **think again the db design**