# Android app not responding (ANR)

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I have an android app, which listens to a socket from the server and retrieves data in json format and save data in the database. Resource cursor adapter is used to display the data  in a list. When the app is idle for 10 minutes or more, it is not reponding. Any solutions?

Comment: where is your code and logcat???

Comment: i edited question to attach the log.

Comment: information inaccuracy and miscellaneous.

Answer (score 17):

`ANR` occurs when the main thread is blocked for a few time. Specifically, 5 seconds in an Activity, 10 seconds in a BroadcastReceiver and 20 seconds in a Service. So, to avoid `ANR`, you need to ensure that you don't do something like these in you UI thread: `reading or writing files`, `connecting the internet`, `operating databases` and so on, which spend a lot of time. So, if you want to do things above, you may start a new thread to do that. Specifically, `AsyncTask` `ThreadHandler` and something like that.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, I remember reading something similar in the Android documentation, but I can not find it anymore, can you please send me the link?

Comment: @dmarin Link is here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Thanks, but it does not longer mention the 20 seconds for the service

Comment: @dmarin if you look up in source codes, you would see `// How long we wait for a service to finish executing.
    static final int SERVICE_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;

    // How long we wait for a service to finish executing.
    static final int SERVICE_BACKGROUND_TIMEOUT = SERVICE_TIMEOUT * 10;` in line 90~94. And in line 1783~1791 of `ActivityManagerService`, you would see `mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(nmsg, ActiveServices.SERVICE_TIMEOUT);`

Answer (score 1):

ANR occurs when Android detects the system is unable to respond to user input for more than a few seconds.

```
CursorWindow﹕ Window is full: requested allocation 396488 bytes,
free space 285853 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
04-01 05:32:34.328    1598-1607/com.inxed W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ 
Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

you need to close the cursor.

Comment: on the on resume of main activity I call two async tasks back to back

Answer (score 0):

ANR display if application cannot respond to the user input.According to the Google doc,you should not perform the work on the UI thread. I recommend you to perform network request or long running operation in worker thread instead of UI thread. for more [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DB cursor its full. After saving data from the cursor, close it, set it to null and create a new one so no buffers are kept in memory.

[this SO answer gives more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15536202/225503)