# Proguard produces java.lang.IllegalStateException on LGE device

Tags: java, android, proguard

When I was testing my app in debug mode using ProGuard, I had encounter a very strange behavior on LGE LG-D850 (LG G3).

The app will not start and I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Only disabling ProGuard, stopped the issue.

When I tried the same APK on Samsung/Nexus it worked just fine.

Another problem is the fact that the stack trace was obfuscated, so I can't know for sure what is the cause.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15536202/1979882

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer, but I saw this post before and it's not proguard related.